# Google chrome older versions for Centos/Linux

Tags: google-chrome, centos, selenium-chromedriver

How can I download google chrome old versions for Centos (. RPM package).

Answer (score 6):

google chrome old versions are here. Currently there has google-chrome-beta-56.0.2924.59-1. x86_64. (.rpm) to google-chrome-unstable-73.0.3642.0-1. x86_64. RPM versions.

Google-chrome old versions  [google-chrome-centos](http://dist.control.lth.se/public/CentOS-7/x86_64/google.x86_64/Packages/)

Comment: We are now in July 2020 and latest version is from 2018!